# I've been testing MySql connection in my new ReactJs NodeJs project but nothing has been inserted into my database. Is there any problem with my code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I've been testing `MySql` connection in my new `ReactJs` `NodeJs` project but nothing has been inserted into my `database`. here is a [screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwnVy.png)

Comment: Please post code, not images of code ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the image you have to use the Post method from your react app using axios or fetch then in your node app you have to define constant from a request ie

```
app.post('api/v1/add/movie',(req,res)=>{
const {movieName,movieReview} = req.body;
//add to db
})
```